# NULL Reference Exception in RichTextbox

Tags: c#, visual-c++

I am writing a dll to capture port pockets (like tcp sniffer) in vc++. This application uses a thread to retrieve pockets continuously and has an event to send data to a `c#` application.

This `c#` appliaction receives that pocket data and stores that data to a .txt file from a richtextbox every 10 seconds and then clears the textbox.

Its running, but sometimes throws a nullreference exception.

errors:

```
at System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.EditStreamProc(IntPtr dwCookie, IntPtr buf, Int32 cb, Int32& transferred)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefWndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: The error is occurring in C# at runtime as you are running a C# app in Visual Studio ... or ... ? How does the C# application "receive" the packet data ? Can we assume you are writing "text only" into the RichTextBox, or are you writing RTF formatted text ? When you speak of "store that data" are you saying you save the contents of the RichTextBox as a text file : is the error occurring before or after you are making the call to save the contents of the RichTextBox ? Are you "validating" in any way, before you insert into the RichTextBox, what you are inserting ? Please clarify, thanks,

Comment: ya..its occuring at runtime only.am using vs 2003
in vc++ application have event in this event only through data to c#. in c# also use event for receive data.dont use any validation .directly put that data to richtextbox and write file in unicode format of txt file.

its working .but after sometime(more then 15 min) only through exception.throw error from void main().

kindly give your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Change your update routine to this:

```
 debugText.SuspendLayout();
 debugText.Focus();
 debugText.SelectionStart = 0;
 debugText.SelectionLength = 0;
 debugText.SelectedText += message;
 debugText.SelectedText += Environment.NewLine;
 debugText.ResumeLayout();
```

Getting focus every time is what fixes the crash.